# Akka. Seed meetup after delayed start

Tags: akka

This is my case:

I have 2 akka seeds (2.4.1). They both have the same cluster config:

```
cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
        "akka.tcp://TestSystem@192.168.88.215:11001"
        "akka.tcp://TestSystem@192.168.30.9:11002"
    ]
}
```

If i start them in same time all will be OK.
If i start them in 30s interval i will receive situation with 2 clusters. Seeds will never meetup by themselves.

Is it correct behavior?

I tried to use

```
seed-node-timeout = 180s
```

but it finished unsuccessfully.

As for me seeds must special pieces of cluster that will be make cluster more stable. And this is reason for me to config behavior when each seed will try to communicate with other seed all time.
Please correct me.